# Does base64 decoding disable search in pdf files?

Tags: android, pdf, base64, decode, encode

There is Arabic encoded pdf file that is received from a server via a web service in my Android application, then I decode it and save it to be cashed to open it anytime,this is the [file](http://pdfmobileservice.star-ware.com/MobileService.svc/GetFile/10122095899/261) I download_which also is encoded_ the problem is the file became not searchable anymore, this is the code I use to decode the file:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... myLink) {

        if (conDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            File myDir = getFilesDir();
            String fileName = PDFCACHE;
            File cachedFile = new File(myDir, fileName);
            // to check if the cached file in the memory or not
            if (cachedFile.exists()) {

                try {
                    readPDFFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (!cachedFile.exists()) {

                try {

                    URL url = new URL(myLink[0]);

                    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.connect();
                    file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                    source = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    buffer = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count = 0;

                    // buffer=new
                    // Scanner(source).useDelimiter("\\A").next().getBytes();*/
                    // buffer = Base64.decode(buffer, 0);

                    for (int i; (i = source.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                        total += i;
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, i); // no doubt here is 0
                        publishProgress(""
                                + (int) ((total * 100) / file_size));
                    }
                    if (flag == false) {
                        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
                        bytes = Base64.decode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                        String decodedString = new String(bytes);
                        if (bytes != null) {
                            openBuffer(bytes);
                            if (manipulateCache())
                                try {
                                    savePDFFile(bytes);
                                    // source.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                        } else {
                            core = openFile(decodedString);

                        }

                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // when there is no internet connection "offline mode"
        } else if (!(conDetector.isConnectingToInternet())) {

            if (!PDFCACHE.equals(null)) {

                try {
                    readPDFFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }       }
```

Comment: this means that the encoding process didn't complete successfully, right? if yes, then is there a specific way to encode it?

Answer (score 0):

The file you received is not searchable, the font objects contain **ToUnicode** maps claiming most of the glyphs used are numbers, symbols, or Latin characters which does not match their appearance as Arabic characters.

Thus, no standard PDF viewer can be used to search the files.